eslint 9 + typescritp without type module
I'm trying to upgrade eslint to v9 for next-json
I followed the official Getting started guideline, but in order to make it work I need to set "type": "module" in the package.json file.
Since I'm distributing the package both as CJS and ESM, I'm warried this setting may create issues on the CJS distributed version.
Can I safely distribute the package with this setting as well?

Why don't you test it? It's hard to say if it will 'just work' because it highly depends on how you set up your commonjs build. Don't guess, get evidence.

Because I'm not strong enough on CJS/ESM topic, @Evert , I don't know how to properly perform the test you are speaking about.

Well since you are building a library targetting CJS, one idea is to create a separate project that uses your library and uses the CJS target.

I actually wrote a guide for having dual target libraries, but actually now recommend people just ditch CommonJS and move on.

From your guide, @Evert , it seems the answer to my question is simply "yes": I see you set "type": "module" in the package.json example... I assume it never caused any promles...

Yeah but my general point stands. Do you really support CJS if you haven't tested it? Having literally no idea is a red flag ;) my packages (when I still supported CommonJS) had unittests for both cases.

I guess the community did it, @Evert ... 2K download / week is not a so big download rate, but it should be enough to make the light green ;)

Yeah of course the alternative is to just throw your code over the hedge and wait for someone to file a bug report. But you asked this question to get more certainty, and the answer obviously is: test your code.

Asking the stackoverflow community to guess for you if your code works is no substitute and a bit silly. You must understand this on some level.

Thank you for the kind conversation, @Evert , but sorry, I can't accept your reproach: I'm not asking to guess for me, the question is excat and precise: "can a package be distributed as CJS with "type": "module" in the package.json file?". Next, if the answer is complex and can be dependant on several unknowns, requiring lots of discussions and hipotesis, it doesn't change how much the question is exact and precise. I asked as I don't know. Thank you for all the info you provided.

Sure, I understand that this could be posed as a theoretical question, for which the answer is: "yes you can".  But given that you're distributing a real library, I don't think it's a completely wild suggestion to first test before asking others if it will fail. Because there are other factors that could cause this to fail. From the looks of it you've been a programmer for a while, and you clearly care about automated tests too judging from your repository? Anyway, good luck with your lib! (fwiw i hope my tone did not sound annoyed, i actually found this somewhat hilarious).

Yes, you can. If you can't set "type": "module" in your package.json, you can still either:

Force the ESLint config file to execute as a module by naming it eslint.config.mjs instead of *.cjs or .js
Use CommonJS syntax in the ESLint config file. Instead of imports and export default [ ... ], you'd use requires and module.exports = [ ... ]:
const eslint = require('eslint');
const tseslint = require('typescript-eslint');

module.exports = [
  eslint.configs.recommended,
  ...tseslint.configs.recommended,
];



This question came up in the typescript-eslint docs: see https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/pull/927 and its linked issues. Naming the ESLint config file eslint.config.mjs is what the typescript-eslint docs now do.
